# Finding small rational solution to under-defined linear equations.

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, rational-numbers

I suspect this is a well studied problem with multiple solution, and I just don't know what terms to search for. If I knew what to search for, I suspect I could figure out how to apply those known techniques to best result for my problem.

So the question is: *What is the name of this category of problem? What technique are know for working with that that I should look into?*

### Abstract formulation

Given:

- $U$ is an known $n\times m$ ($n>m$) matrix of rational values.
- $u$ is an $1\times m$ vector, also rational.

Solve $s\times U=u$ optimized such that $s$ is:

- sparse
- mostly integers
- small values

### Practical formulation

I have a value that is tagged with physical units in terms of the 7 base SI units raised to rational powers and a collection of units (more properly; classes of units) expressed in the same form. I want to find a "reasonable" representation of that physical unit in terms of a small number of named complex units to simple powers.

For example: $\frac{m^2 kg}{s^3 mol}=\frac{J}{s\cdot mol}$

Comment: multiply by the denominators to obtain natural instead of rational numbers and use mixed integer optimization

Comment: I assume that's the LCM of the denominators? Also: does the "mostly integers" constraint (which then becomes a discreet-math/mod constraint) negate the advantage that gives?

Comment: mixed integer optimization is not simple, but you can model everything you mentioned and leave the hard work to specialized software